# Visual Studio Community 2019 Debugger Not Preempting Chrome Debugger with Blazor Wasm App

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-2019

I am playing with a Blazor Wasm app on VS Community 2019 v16.6.2 using AspNetCore v3.2.0 and Chrome v83.0.4103.   When I set a break point in some native javascript in VS, Chrome breaks on that statement instead of VS as shown in the screenshot below (look for the small light yellow "Paused in debugger" popup).  This has happened before, but then I discovered I had '"nativeDebugging": true,' in the IIS Express profile in launchSettings.json.  I got rid of it, and the problem went away.  Now it is back, without nativeDebugging set.  This is a giant pain.  Any idea what I am missing this time?

Thanks.  Steve

[image]

Comment: The problem just went away when I opened the .map file for a TypeScript file that was not loading (though its generated JavaScript file clearly was loading).  I didn't make any changes.  I just opened the file and looked at it.  Curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a real answer.  As I said above, the problem went away when I merely opened the .map file for the TypeScript file.  I assume that triggered some rebuild-like process, but that's purely conjecture.